# Connectivity of Streams

Tags: hydrology, rivers, stream-order, connectivity-analysis

I have a line vector layer containing streams (see image below). What is the easiest approach to determine the connectivity of each stream segment (eg. sum of upstream nodes)?

[image]

Comment: I'm almost positive this question has been asked before, but using different terminology - maybe a specific name (similar to Strahler Order) for this type of ranking or statistic? I searched for a bit but can't find the one I'm thinking of. I don't do a lot of geometric network analysis, but I'm thinking you'd have to use some kind of iterative flow analysis or network trace to get the count of all upstream segments from any given segment and write that as an attribute. There are a few people here much more familiar with stream/hydrology analysis than I though.

Comment: Thanks for the info Chris, I deleted my answer so not to confuse anyone.

Comment: If you use ArcGIS then have a look at [RivEX](http://www.rivex.co.uk).

Comment: Does a good open source alternative for RIvEX exist?

Answer (score -1):

I use archydrotools for accumulate attributes downstream in simmilar type of network...
I'm sorry. I don't speak English very well so I can't explain now...